# How do I solve this to represent the complex number in Cartesian coordinate

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

How do I solve this to represent the complex number in Cartesian coordinate

$$z=\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}}{e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}\cdot 2e^{\frac{\pi}{6}i}}$$

So I got this question as a homework and I am not able to solve it correctly. Any leads on how to solve this would help.

Comment: What do you want to solve ?

Comment: The image link is given

Comment: Don't use links in your question and rather make the effort to type it using MathJax.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will use it from next time. New to stack exchange mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For any $x\in\mathbb R$, you have

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

also known as Euler's formula.

---

So, e.g. considering $e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}$, as $\pi/3\in\mathbb R$, we have

$$e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}=\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3)=\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

You can proceed to use this conversion of polar to cartesian representations to convert the other expressions. Then, you may proceed to do arithmetic on those cartesian-represented numbers as usual.

Comment: Yes I saw this equation online. So i have to use this and solve the equation first and represent in cartesian coordinate?

Comment: @ardentcoder I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you . Will proceed with this.